# Which permission to request for application to post on user's wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the FB JavaScript SDK and I'm trying to get the app to request a permission from the user to post on the user's wall.

I was looking at the [Facebook Graph API permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) but I'm not sure which permission should I request from the user!

Comment: oh no! im must be too sleepy. i just found it, it is publish_stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 'publish_stream' permissions.